# passing/return our own types

Tags: java, rmi

When running i am getting this error:

java MyRemoteClient

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy2 cannot be cast to Account
    `enter code here`at MyRemoteImpl_Stub.addAccount(Unknown Source)
    at MyRemoteClient.main(MyRemoteClient.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.symbol.JavaClass$JavaMethod.evaluate(JavaClass.java:362)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.handleMethodCall(ExpressionEvaluator.java:92)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.visit(ExpressionEvaluator.java:84)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.StaticMethodCall.acceptVisitor(StaticMethodCall.java:121)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:38)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:37)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:106)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:29)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.ExpressionStatement.acceptVisitor(ExpressionStatement.java:101)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.evaluateSequence(StatementEvaluator.java:66)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:77)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:47)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:246)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:220)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
```

I did a similar program that using primitives and String as paramaters or return types, it works fine, for e.g,

```
public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
```

but something like

```
public Greet sayHello(Job j) throws RemoteException;
```

will fail to run and generate error like the one above.

I tried to implement [b]Serializable[/b] with all all the classes but i am still getting this error.

Here are all the codes:

AccountInterface.java

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface AccountInterface extends Remote {
  public float deposit(float amt) throws RemoteException;
  public float withdrawal(float amt) throws RemoteException;
  public String checkBalance() throws RemoteException;
  public String accDetails() throws RemoteException;
}
```

[/code]

Account.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Account extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AccountInterface, Serializable{
private static int nextId = 0;
public int accNumber;
private String name;
private String address;
private float balance;

public Account(String n, String a, float b) throws RemoteException{
accNumber = ++nextId;
name = n;
address= a;
balance= b;
}

  public float deposit(float amt) throws RemoteException {
  balance += amt;
  return balance;
}

public float withdrawal(float amt) throws RemoteException {
  balance -= amt;
  return balance;
}

public String checkBalance() throws RemoteException{
  return (String.format("Balance=Rs.%,.2f\n", balance));
}

public String accDetails() throws RemoteException{

String s = String.format("Name=%s, Address=%s\n",
                         name, address);
return s;
 }
}
```

MyRemote.java

```
 import java.rmi.*;

    public interface MyRemote extends Remote {
     public Account addAccount(String n, String a, float b) throws RemoteException;
     public int getTotalAccount() throws RemoteException;
     public Account getObject(int id) throws RemoteException;
     public String deleteAccount(int id) throws RemoteException;
    }

MyRemoteImpl.java
    import java.rmi.*;
    import java.rmi.server.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class MyRemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote, Serializable {
    private  ArrayList<Account> acct = new ArrayList<Account>();

    public Account addAccount(String n, String a, float b) throws RemoteException{
    Account acc = null;
    try {
      acc = new Account(n,a,b);
      acct.add(acc);
    } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

    return acc;
   }

   public int getTotalAccount()  throws RemoteException{
    return acct.size();
   }

   public Account getObject(int id) {

    try {
      for (Account a : acct) {
        if (a.accNumber == id) return a;
      }
    } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    return null;

   }

   public String deleteAccount(int id)  throws RemoteException{
    int index = -1;

    try {
      for (Account a : acct) {
        index++;
        if (a.accNumber == id) break;
      }
    } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    acct.remove(index);
    return "Account deleted.";
   }


   public MyRemoteImpl() throws RemoteException { }

   public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
      MyRemote service = new MyRemoteImpl();
      Naming.rebind("AccountDirectory", service);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   }
```

MyRemoteClient.java

```
     import java.rmi.*;
     import java.util.*;
     import java.io.Serializable;

     public class MyRemoteClient implements Serializable {
     public static void main (String[] args) {

     try {
      MyRemote service = (MyRemote) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/AccountDirectory");

      Account a = (Account) service.addAccount("John", "Texas", 20000); //Dnt know if this is good, tryinh to cast it to Account 
      Account b = (Account) service.addAccount("Paul", "California", 35000);
      Account temp = service.getObject(1);
      temp.deposit(1000);
      temp.withdrawal(1000);
      System.out.println(temp.accDetails());

    } catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   }
```

Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Try this: AccountInterface a = service.addAccount

Comment: @Usman: Correct. You should post that as an answer, not a comment!

Comment: You also need to change the methods in `MyRemote` to return `AccountInterface`, not `Account`. The rule in RMI is that the interfaces exposed over RMI can only refer to other remote interfaces, and to serializable classes (including primitives), never the implementation classes.

Comment: By the way, the usual convention is that the interfaces have the simple names (`Account`, `MyRemote`, or perhaps `AccountService`), and the implementations have names ending `Impl` (`AccountImpl`, `MyRemoteImpl`, `AccountServiceImpl`). Then an implementation class stands out like a sore thumb, and you are less likely to refer to it by mistake.

Comment: I am now getting 
$Proxy2 cannot be cast to AccountInterface
(thanks for the tip, did not know that :) )

Comment: There is something else going wrong with your program. Either your Account class is not exported correctly or there is some other classpath issue on the client side. Is there any particular reason you are exporting your Account class from UniCastRemote object? Also, make sure to restart your rmi registry (or better to invoke it programmatically - which solves many classpath issues).

Answer (score 0):

Your domain objects should only implement `Serializable`, nothing more:

```
public class Account implements Serializable
```

RMI is fully capable of marshalling/unmarshalling any Java object that is serializable (like primitives or `String`s).

Comment: It looks to me like the author's intent is that Account should be a distributed object, with remote clients accessing a single instance on the server. That's how a bank account would usually work. In that case, it doesn't need to `Serializable` (although it doesn't hurt if it is), but the author shouldn't expect to be able to cast references to it to `Account`, only `AccountInterface`.

Comment: I believe you might be right. Please post your comment as an answer so the OP can decide.

Comment: I changed the line to AccountInterface a = service.addAccount but i am still getting the same error. An explanation of the program: I have an object that is an arrayList of type Account and contain references to Account objects. I did a similar program with no custom type(like Account)- only with primitives and String as return types with exactly the same logic and it worked. Any other solutions?

Comment: @Tomasz: I was expecting Usman Saleem, who had commented on the question, to post more or less that answer, and i didn't want to preempt him. We'll see if he does.

Answer (score 0):

i manage to make it work. I removed the AccountInterface completely, since it lives inside the server itself and client wont interact with it directly. Thanks!